# File names in programs: why the need for them?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm learning the basics of programming, and am currently going over calling files in pseodocode.

My text explains the process of calling a file to read or write to, but it doesn't explain why we have an internal name to reference a file to which we read or write. When I was reviewing with a friend, we thought perhaps it's because the program itself would need something like a variable to reference the actual file in memory.

Would anyone mind clarifying why we reference existing files in memory with a file name in a program? I would really appreciate the understanding.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "internal name". Can you show an example?

Comment: That's about it. The file have a name on disk. You call a function to "open" the file so it can be accessed inside the program. The "open" function returns some kind of handle or reference to the libraries or system internal structures. This handle or reference must be stored in a variable. What you call this variable is up to you.

Comment: I'd say because of object-oriented programming. You usually don't have global built-in functions for reading or writing lines to a file. Instead, those are methods of some `File` class. And "opening" a file and binding it to some "internal name" is just the act of creating an instance of such a class, providing the methods for reading/writing to that particular file.

Comment: Sure!  For example.... Open internalName "someData.dat"  that is a line of pseudocode that represents opening the file in memory someData.dat . I am at a loss to explain why we don't just open the file and directly read or write to it.   In the example pseudocode they show a write statement like...   Write internalName "new datum"

Comment: Maybe you should show an example of the pseudo-code in question. Also: It's called pseudo-code for a reason; don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we name objects in programs is to separate their semantic meaning from their transient features.

In your case, a program may let the user place a file in a directory, other than the default one. In that case the filename would change accordingly, while the internal name used by the program to refer to the file object would remain.